# Need to get rid of lang version in url

Tags: contao

Have a project on Contao CMS 3.3.6.
Main page adress has url: sitename.com/en/
Even try sitename.com, whatever redirecting to sitename.com/en/
I have tried fix it by using htaccess but it is not works: too many redirects.
Also I didn`t find redirects type of

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://sitename.com/xx");
```

How can fix it? Or where I need to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need .htaccess to do that. Go to the backend settings. Uncheck 'add language to url' in the front end configuration fieldset. That should do it. First reverse what you have done with the htaccess file

Comment: It works. But how can I set another language(dufault language is en) as default? Thanks.

Comment: Please accept then as an answer. To use another language go to backend under root page. Add a language fallback e.g es,de etc. That means you have to check 'add language to url'. That is if you want to remove en and use another language.